# How to replace different possible substrings (maybe even of different lengths) with a single substring?

Tags: java, python, string, algorithm, substring

Suppose I have a huge string in following format -

```
"blahblahblahrgb(123, 214, 255)blahblahrgb(99, 0, 235)aefubaeofbiuaebfaef"
```

And I want to replace each instance of "rgb(x,x,x)" with "rgb(255,255,255)", with rest of the cahracters in string left intact. I can't use default string replace method as values inside rgb() can vary.

So the above string should become -

```
"blahblahblahrgb(255, 255, 255)blahblahrgb(255, 255, 255)aefubaeofbiuaebfaef"
```

Is there a default function to do that? or any efficient logic you can suggest?

Python, Javascript, Java, Dart or any language would do.

Comment: It's looks like a simple string replace, can you show what you have tried so far & be specific on language tag, don't spam by adding multiple tags.

Comment: Not spamming. I didn't have any idea around it, so asked here. A simple replace would work like mystring.replace("rgb(123,123,123)","rgb(255,255,255)"). But I can't simply provide rgb(123,123,123) as the values inside rgb() may vary.

Comment: Your questions sounds like an implementation of REGEX is required or the use of position, stripping and temp vars

Comment: This site is about being specific however so please specify a language. We don't even know if the use you have planned will even work with whatever language we chose

Comment: Sorry about that. I just have a huge code which contains different colours. I was just looking for a way to replace all of them with rgb(255,255,255) at once. So I though I'd put the whole code in a string and use some sort of replace technique. Thats why I didn't care about language, just need to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick regex solution in Java

```java
public String replaceAllRGBToWhite(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("rgb\\(\\d{1,3}, \\d{1,3}, \\d{1,3}\\)", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. thats exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a perfect usecase for [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
Since you asked for multiple languages, here is a python regex version.

```
import re
rex = re.compile("rgb\(\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}, \d{1,3}\)")
myString = "blahblahblahrgb(123, 214, 255)blahblahrgb(99, 0, 235)aefubaeofbiuaebfaef"
newString = rex.sub("rgb(255, 255, 255)", mystring)

print(myString)
>>> blahblahblahrgb(123, 214, 255)blahblahrgb(99, 0, 235)aefubaeofbiuaebfaef

print(newString)
>>> blahblahblahrgb(255, 255, 255)blahblahrgb(255, 255, 255)aefubaeofbiuaebfaef
```

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UoUZ3R/1/) for a step by step explanation of the regex.